Review gym routine for beginner
My gym trainer gave me this routine.
Could you review it for me?
I am a beginner.
Just started going to the gym.
Routine
Day 1: Upper Body (Chest, Back, Shoulders)
Warm-Up:

5-10 minutes of light cardio
Dynamic stretches (e.g., arm circles, shoulder rolls)

Exercises:

Incline Press: 4 sets of 8-12 reps Rows (Weighted or Bodyweight): 4
sets of 8-12 reps
Pull-Downs with Close Grip: 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Bicep Curls or Hammer Curls: 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Lateral Raise: 3 sets of 12-15 reps

Cool-Down:

5-10 minutes of stretching (focus on chest, shoulders, and back)

Day 2: Lower Body (Quads, Glutes, Hamstrings)
Warm-Up:

5-10 minutes of light cardio
Dynamic stretches (e.g., leg swings, hip circles)

Exercises:

High Bar Squats or Machine Squats: 4 sets of 8-12 reps
Romanian Deadlifts (RDLs): 3 sets of 8-12 reps
Lunges: 3 sets of 10-12 reps per leg
Hamstring Curls: 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Deadlifts (if comfortable and with proper form): 3 sets of 6-8 reps

Cool-Down:

5-10 minutes of stretching (focus on legs and lower back)

Day 3: Active Rest (Cardio and Core)
Activities:

Light activities like walking, yoga, or swimming
Cardio: 20-30 minutes of moderate-intensity cardio

Core Exercises:

Planks: 3 sets, hold for 30-60 seconds each
Side Planks: 3 sets, hold for 30-45 seconds each side
Russian Twists: 3 sets of 15-20 reps per side

Recovery:

Foam rolling and additional stretching

Day 4: Upper Body (Arms and Shoulders)
Warm-Up:

5-10 minutes of light cardio
Dynamic stretches

Exercises:

Bench Press or Overhead Press: 4 sets of 8-12 reps (choose based on preference and goals)
Face Pulls: 3 sets of 12-15 reps
Bicep Curls (Variety of variations): 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Tricep Dips or Tricep Pushdowns: 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Rows (Weighted or Bodyweight): 3 sets of 8-12 reps

Cool-Down:

5-10 minutes of stretching

Day 5: Lower Body (Focus on Strength)
Warm-Up:

5-10 minutes of light cardio
Dynamic stretches

Exercises:

High Bar Squats or Machine Squats: 4 sets of 6-8 reps (heavier weight)
Romanian Deadlifts (RDLs): 3 sets of 8-12 reps
Leg Press: 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Glute Bridges: 3 sets of 12-15 reps

Cool-Down:

5-10 minutes of stretching

Day 6: Active Rest (Cardio and Core)
Activities:

Light activities like walking, yoga, or swimming
Cardio: 20-30 minutes of moderate-intensity cardio

Core Exercises:

Planks: 3 sets, hold for 30-60 seconds each
Leg Raises: 3 sets of 10-15 reps
Bicycle Crunches: 3 sets of 15-20 reps per side

Forearm Exercises:

Wrist Curls (Palms Up): 3 sets of 8-12 reps
Reverse Wrist Curls (Palms Down): 3 sets of 8-12 reps
Farmer's Walks: 3 sets, walk for 30-60 seconds each set

Recovery:

Foam rolling and additional stretching

Day 7: Rest

Complete rest day


it would help if you could [edit] the question to add some extra context: how old are you and what's your goal with this program: hypertrophy, strength, general conditioning, or something else.

Overall, I think this is a fine exercise selection and workout organization. If you enjoy the exercise selection and motivation to train stays consistent, this is a perfectly acceptable and effective way to train for general strength and muscle hypertrophy.
The only shortcoming I see with what you’ve written here is a lack of progression or loading scheme. One of the key principles for continuing to make progress in the gym is progressive overload. We want to make sure we are providing a consistent challenge to our muscles so that we are giving them a reason to adapt, and as they adapt, we need to increase one or more training variables to continue adapting. Next time you speak with the trainer that provided you with this program, ask them for some additional guidance on loading and progression, and you’ll have a well rounded and effective program.

I generally agree with Thomas assessment of the workout regime on a pure physical perspective.
But from a psychological point of view it is probably to much.
As I read it this is a program for training 6 of 7 days in a week.
If you are an experienced athlete this might be ok for you.
But you write you are a beginner and going from 0 to 6 times a week in the gym doesn't sound  sustainable to me.
It is bound to end like all those new year resolutions.
Start slow, with once or twice a week and make that a habit.
Then grow that.

I fully agree on this addition, as an other beginner I found the hard way that going to often to the gym would sometimes turn it onto a chore, although when I reduced the frequency, I would crave for next training during rest day. But I guess It would depend a lot on individuals.

Have you heard of the Milo Wolf 52 sets per group per week study?
You're warm up is a small workout. I personally skip warming up as isometric strength exercises strech the muscles.
Cardio counteracts your muscle growth (size), try rucking instead (walking with a backpack). Do you want to get muscular, or skinny?
Dr Mike Metzer trained to failure.
